# ¿Como crear pdf de graficas echas con C3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, pdf, jquery-ui

Tengo un div con dos tablas en la parte izquierda y dos graficas en la parte derecha realizadas con C3.js.

[image: Imagen]

Esto lo quiero exportar a pdf, lo hice con html2canvas y jsPDF el detalle de esto es que como toma captura y lo guarda en un pdf , la imagen no sale de tan buena calidad, incluso se ven estiradas las letras y graficas..
Tambien lo he realizado con Kendo, con esto si me guarda de buena calidad , pero unicamente aparecen las tablas, las graficas no se visualizan en el pdf.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy programando en laravel y tampoco me genera el pdf con dompdf, para hacer las graficas necesito de un js y en la vista para el dompdf no me hagarran los js insertados, es por eso que no se visualizan las graficas.

Necesito que las graficas aparezcan!, porfavor si alguien sabe que puedo hacer para que aparezcan, o que opciones hay para crear un pdf de buena calidad y que se vean las graficas.